# List with values not found in another list when each index has two objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

As the question already says, my code returns a list with the index's that don't exist inside another list.

For this I currently create two lists joining the objects of each index, then filter the values not found and finally I do a loop searching in which index I will find this value within the initial list:

```javascript
function notfind() {
  const history = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
  const history_join = [];
  var i=0;
  var max = history.length;
  for(i; i<max; i++){
    history_join.push(history[i][0] + history[i][1]);
  }
  
  const new_values = [['c','d'],['e','f']]
  const new_values_join = [];
  var i=0;
  var max = new_values.length;
  for(i; i<max; i++){
    new_values_join.push([new_values[i][0] + new_values[i][1]]);
  }

  const not_match = new_values_join.filter(x => !history_join.includes(x[0]));
  
  var not_contains = [];
  var i=0;
  var max = new_values_join.length;
  for(i; i<max; i++) {
    if (not_match.includes(new_values_join[i])) {
      not_contains.push(new_values[i])
    }
  }
  console.log(not_contains);
}
```

Output:

```
[['e','f']]
```

I would like a review of the method to improve the execution time and number of tasks until reaching the desired result.

---

**Additional information of a method security flaw found by @DaveMeehan:**

> What if history was `[‘a’,’b’]` and new values was `[‘ab’,’’]`

Comment: Is concatenating the two values reliable?  What if history was `[‘a’,’b’]` and new values was `[‘ab’,’’]`?  Why is it necessary to concatenating when comparing the elements of history and new would appear to suffice?

Comment: Hi @DaveMeehan , I really hadn't thought of that, it's a serious security issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution can be simplified to a few lines.

---

This peice of code is written twice in your function and simply creates a list of "keys" to identify each sub array of your list.

```javascript
for(i; i<max; i++){
  history_join.push(history[i][0] + history[i][1]);
}
```

You could create a function that handles building the key and call it whenever you want.

```javascript
const buildKey = arr => arr.join('');
```

The advantage of that is, you won't be limitted to two items of your sub array.

---

You're also playing around with multiple lists within your function but that seems to overly complicate your end goal.

You should instead:

1. Build keys from your `history` list and store efficient [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object.
2. Build keys from your `new_values` list and see if it exists in the Set object.
3. If the new_value key doesn't exist in Set well you can filter it out.

---

Full solution:

```js
const buildKey = arr => arr.join(':');

const notFound = (input, history) => {
  const historySet = new Set(history.map(buildKey));
  return input.filter((arr) => !historySet.has(buildKey(arr)))
}

const history = [['a','b'],['c','d']];
const input = [['c','d'],['e','f'], ['ab', '']];

const result = notFound(input, history);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi @kemicofaghost , 
Dave Meehan brought a very important security point that I hadn't noticed and that your option also fell into the same trap, if there is a new value ```[‘ab’,’’]```, it doesn't appear as a ```result``` list because if join values, ```ab``` will continue to be ```ab```.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer then just do `join(':')` when building the key.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I asked about concatenation is that its unnecessary unless you wanted to catch matching concatenations regardless of the inputs.  It seems that's not the case, so why not just compare elements?

```
const notFound = (input, history) => {
    return input.filter(inItem => {
        return !history.find(histItem => {
            return inItem.length === histItem.length && inItem.reduce((acc, cur, index) => cur === histItem[index], true)
        })
    })
}

const history = [['a','b'],['c','d']];
const input = [['c','d'],['e','f'], ['ab', '']];

const result = notFound(input, history);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

After @DaveMeehan's comment:

> Is concatenating the two values reliable? What if history was
> `[‘a’,’b’]` and new values was `[‘ab’,’’]`? Why is it necessary to
> concatenating when comparing the elements of history and new would
> appear to suffice?

I noticed the severe problem encountered in concatenating the values, so an option to fix the problem was:

```js
const history = [['a','b'],['c','d']];
const new_values = [['c','d'],['ab',''],['e','f']];

const result = [];
for (var key of new_values) {
  if (!JSON.stringify(history).includes(JSON.stringify(key))) {
    result.push(key)
  }
}
console.log(result)
```